# What is the equivalent method in Java to map in haskell or select in C#?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

Is there any built-in function in Java similar either to the map function in Haskell or Schema or to the Select extensor method in C#?
I just want to write this kind of code in a shorter way:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
foreach (User element : getUsers()) {
   names.add(element.getName());
};
return names;
```

a shorter way (in C#)

```
List<String> names = getUsers().Select(x => x.getName()).ToList();
```

I also need a way of pass function as parameter in a "friendly" way.

Comment: Take a look at Java 8's streams. If you cannot use Java 8, then create an interface that has the method signature you need and anonymous class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 8, this would look something like

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

List<String> names = getUsers().stream().map(User::getName).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score -2):

Using streams in Java 8, you can do the following:

```
List<String> names = getUsers().stream().map(User::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of mapping the stream?